# How to enumerate the elements of a string array in a dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary with values of array of strings. lets call it dic

```
Dictionary<int, string[]> dic;
```

how can i enumerate the items of a specific Value array?

Comment: You retrieve the value and iterate it like a normal array.. What are you having problems with?

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate around the string array like this:

```
foreach(string s in dic[myIntKey])
{
  // do something
}
```

Obviously you'll have issues if your dictionary does not have element at the given location so you'll need to use [ContainsKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if you're at all unsure.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<int, string[]> dic = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
string[] stringArray = dic[0];

// Enumerate through stringArray
foreach (string str in stringArray)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: i found it out, thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
Dictionary<int, string[]> dic;
//initialize your dictionary.

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string[]> entry in dic)
{
    int key = entry.Key;
    foreach (string item in entry.Value)
    {
        //your string entries
    }
}
```

For specific entry check :

```
int key = 1;
if (dic.ContainsKey(key))
{
    foreach (string item in dic[key])
    {
        //your string entries
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the dots for?

Comment: for rest codes to set dictionary

Comment: You should put it as comment then (// ...) and not like that, is this code as it is would not compile

Comment: we have a keyword named `var` in c# :-) also you are getting Key with `int key = entry.Key` but you didn't use it anywhere.I don't understand your point

Comment: @Selman22, only because we have something does not mean you have to use it right? The OP is obviously a beginner in C# and keeping the variable declarations strong typed may help in the beginning to understand stuff

Comment: Its just for to get the key, if he needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ForEach` extension of a `string[]`

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string[]> kvp in dic)
{
    Array.ForEach(dic[kvp.Key], x => { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(kvp.Key+":"+x); });
}
```